# ASP.NET AJAX pageLoad() not firing (formerly: "with StyleSheetTheme, does with Theme?")

Tags: asp.net, ajax, pageload

**Updated - Title changed b/c `StyleSheetTheme` and `Theme` have nothing to do with it -- see answer for details.**

I'm working on a page that has descended, through several years and a few intermediary stages, from another page that successfully uses the AJAX `pageLoad()` function to perform some (re-)initialization on full and partial postbacks.

The `pageLoad()` on this new page was not firing. A systematic comparison of the two pages (`.aspx` and `.js` files) eventually led me to a surprising (to me, anyway) difference that was causing the failure: the old page's `@ Page` directive specified a `Theme="foo"`, whereas the new page's directive specified a `StyleSheetTheme="foo"`. Changing StyleSheetTheme to Theme restores the triggering of the `pageLoad()` function.

In this new page I can live with the (non-overridable) Theme settings, so I don't actually have a problem that needs solving in this momemt, but I thought the behavior was not obvious and worth noting, and if someone has insight into the reason(s) StyleSheetTheme might block firing of `pageLoad()` I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation with the page referenced in the question as well as other similar pages revealed that the problem had nothing to do with changing between the `StyleSheetTheme` and `Theme` attributes of the `@ Page` directive. I changed the question/title to reflect this.

The actual reason the `pageLoad()` function was not being triggered in the particular Javascript file I was working on is that there was already another `pageLoad()` function defined in a separate Javascript file being used by the page, and *it* was the one being executed because it was included later and over-rode/replaced the one I was working on. I found this using a script debugger by locating the pageLoad handling within the ScriptResource.axd file (in function Sys$_Application$raiseLoad()) and following execution into the second, over-riding script file... Palm, meet forehead...

Takeaway points:

- only one `pageLoad()` can operate at the page level without resorting to some kind of scheme to daisy-chain multiple scripts; I opted for [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630341/sys-application-add-load-vs-document-ready-vs-pageload#12866224) so each of my script files can add its own (re-)initialization to the chain without clobbering any that are already there
- using the `StyleSheetTheme` attribute vs the `Theme` attribute had *nothing* to do with my problem
- try to be (even more) careful to ensure clear and clean tests before posting to SO... I *thought* that I had done a simple A/B test of the page directive attributes and that it had solved the problem, but upon discovering the true cause I went back to review the screen-captures (I use for time-tracking) and discovered that I had made *two* changes, not just one, before observing the change in behavior. It was the *other* change (removing another Javascript file from my page) that had fixed it, but during an interruption between the changes and final testing I forgot that I'd done it