# Add script on Page load c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a script to the page but nothing happens, the calendar does not appear.
The objective is to render a calendar with a list of events, im trying to avoid webservices to get the list.

```
  string CalendarScript = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
        jQuery(function ($) {

            /* initialize the external events
                -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

                // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
                // it doesn't need to have a start or end
                var eventObject = {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
                };

                // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
                $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                });

            });

            /* initialize the calendar
            -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();


            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                lang: ""pt"",
                allDaySlot: false,
                minTime: ""07:00:00"", 
                maxTime: ""23:59:59"",

                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

                header: {
                    left: ' ',
                    center: ' ',
                    right: ' '
                },
                events: [ " + EventsList + @"
                ]
    ,

                columnFormat: {

                    week: 'dddd', 

                },

                editable: false,
                droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!

                selectable: false,
                selectHelper: false


            });


        })
    </script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "InitCalendarEvents", CalendarScript, false);
```

where the EventList is like this

```
   { title: 'Some Event', start: new Date(y, m, d - 2, 16, 00), end: new Date(y, m, d - 2, 17, 00), allDay: false,  color: 'blue !important',  textColor: 'white !important' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, when you use register a script with the script manager, it should be just the javascript and not wrapped in a script tag. Second, you will most likely want the function to occur on the the add_load event.

This is a sample snippet:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "StartupScript", 
    "Sys.Application.add_load(function() { functioncall(); });", 
    true);
```

Note that the parameter for the javascript function is a javascript function and not an html script element. Also, not that the function is composed into `Sys.Application.add_load`

If you do those two things, the script should at least be executed. The question [Sys.application.add_load vs document ready vs pageload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630341/sys-application-add-load-vs-document-ready-vs-pageload) is probably relevant to what you are trying to do.