# calling javascript from code behind vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What I'm trying to do is to use javascript function to autoclick a button as method for error handling. The javascript work just fine with onClick on the button .The problem that I faced is that the javascript called does not work at all when I called it from the code behind. Am I doing it wrong?

here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callbtn() {
    document.getElementById("btnAlert").click();
}
 </script>
```

and here is the method that I used to call javascript from code behind:

```
If CheckLotIDExist = "Y" Then
 'do something here
Else
    LblMsg.Text = "Lot Not Foundzz!"
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "script", "callbtn();", True)
End If
```

Comment: are you getting any error in cosole?

Comment: also put alert in your function to check its getting executed or not

Comment: there are no error in the console. I've use breakpoint to check whether the script executed ..so I''m sure that the javascript does not execute

Comment: put alert in your callbtn() javascript function

Comment: and instead of RegisterStartupScript use RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: I've tried RegisterClientScriptBlock  and the result still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const string script = "function f(){callbtn(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "keyLicDtlz", script, true);
```

Comment: ermm..explain please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630341/sys-application-add-load-vs-document-ready-vs-pageload