# Generating a separate CSS file vs. Injecting CSS directly into a <style> tag (when building React apps)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to React and I want to ask: Should I use `style-loader` or `mini-css-extract-plugin` when configuring webpack? I am reading that using `mini-css-extract-plugin` is better for caching purposes and that using `style-loader` may sometimes lead to FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content) since the browser may need some slight time to load JS.

Comment: It looks like you've got two arguments for mini-css-extract-plugin and none for style-loader. In reality there are 10 million downloads a week for one and 8 million for the other, so they're both fine.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a site for gathering "thoughts" (opinions) on which x is better or should I use x or y to do z? Please see the [help/on-topic] and [ask] to see what kinds of questions are on topic.

Comment: Heretic Monkey, well it is kinda weird that you are saying this and I find this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630341/sys-application-add-load-vs-document-ready-vs-pageload/3736691#3736691) where you finish your question with (any ideas/"thoughts"). Don't criticize when you do the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

its totally upto You.

But when you will work on big projects. Managing the code will be more complicated. so i recomended you to use seperate css file.

if you want to avoid global styling you can also do that in react by using css modules. to learn more about css modules [click here](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/basic-concepts/css-modules/)

also you can use Styled components to write `scss` like codes
to learn more about Styled components [click here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics)

Thank you